# Disabled variable is one step behind the actual value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I think there's an issue in ionic-angular latest update because the same code is working fine in previous versions.

```
<ion-button [disabled]="currentState === -1" (click)="changeState('undo')" fill="clear">
   <ion-icon size="large" name="arrow-undo" slot="start"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

I'm making a sketch app in which undo button is disabled when `currentState === -1`. As I draw something, I increment the value of `currenState` by `+1`. But the problem is that button is still disabled when `currenState === 0` and is enabled when `currenState === 1`. That means the variable in disabled condition is one step behind the actual value. Why is that happening? I also consoled the value of `currentState`, its not changing in the code.

Comment: `[disabled]="currentState == -1 ? true : false"` pass True or False in your disabled attribute.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Same output is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <ion-button [disabled]="currentState === -1 ? true : false" (click)="changeState('undo')" fill="clear">
   <ion-icon size="large" name="arrow-undo" slot="start"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```